# Why won't the background color of my modal content show?

Tags: javascript, css, html

```js
// Get the modal
let modal = document.getElementById('login-modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
let btn = document.getElementById("login");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "flex";
}

// When the user clicks on the <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close the modal
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";}
}
```

```css
html, body{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:100%;
}

body{
 min-height:100%;
 min-width:100%;
 background-color:blue;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 position:relative;
 
}
.container{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#login-modal{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 text-align:center;
}

.login-content{
 border: 10 px solid black;
 height:300px;
 width:500px;
 background-color:white;
 text-align:center;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password]{
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
   <div  id="branding">
    <a href="indexresolve.html"><img src="images/lasttry.png" alt="resolvelogo"></a>
   </div>
   <nav>
    <li><a href="indexresolve.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="howitworks.html">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><button id="login" class="button">Log In</button></li>
    <div id="login-modal">
     <div id="login-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <form>
       <input type="text" placeholder="username">
       <input type="password" placeholder="password">
       <button>Log In</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
 </header>
```

I have my modal content div ready to go with basic css, but the background color of white doesnt show. I want there to be a 200px by 300px white box for the background of my content.

```
<div id="login-modal">
<div id="login-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="username">
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
<button>Log In</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>


#login-modal{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
}

.login-content{
border: 10 px solid black;
height:300px;
width:500px;
background-color:white;
text-align:center;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password]{
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

I thought setting the background color of the modal itself with an rgba would help but still the white box is not there.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You can do this with the built in code snippet feature in S.O. or on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can see that an rgba background color is added when you click on login button

Answer (score 0):

do the following change in css

```
#login-modal {
    width: 61%;
    height: 39%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```